# SQLite date conversion issue on Windows 8.1 store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, sqlite-net

I have developed a Windows 8.1 Store app using SQLite as the DB. From the backend I receive `Datetime` data in a format like this "3/24/2017 5:53:24 PM", and I save it to a SQLite database with no issues.
My PC OS (Windows 10) has the "Short Date" in a format of "M/d/yyyy"

Then I change the "Short Date" format to "dd-MMM-yy" and try to retrieve the data SQLite throws an exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".

How do I stop Windows date format change effect on my app. I want to declare a DateTime format on my app globally.

This is the code throws the exception.

```
var mListX = connSync.Table<DB.Meeting>().Where(h => h.IsUpdated == (byte)EncryptionType.Encrypted)
```

DB.Meeting model is as follows

```
public class Meeting
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int MeetingId { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "Then I change the "Short Date" format to "dd-MMM-yy" and try to retrieve the data SQLite" when ?

Comment: When I change the "Short Date" format I restart the app. After that, it throws the above error. Basically, my app only works when Windows date format is "M/d/yyyy". I want to make my app work regardless of the date format on Windows OS. Thank you.

Comment: According to this Sqlite parses date using invariant culture https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net/SQLiteCommand.cs#L476 so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: what library you are using ?